# Card not showing; goes straight to home card

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I am trying to show a card so I know everything up to that point works. However, when I try to display the card, it just goes straight to the home card. The card I was trying to show was just going to display what was said in the voice recognizer before but that didn't work so I just put plain text and that didn't work either. Application goes - voice trigger --> voice recognizer --> this service:

```
public class MedMinderService extends Service {
public String MedName;
public String voiceResults;
private static final String TAG = "ShowData";
private static final String LIVE_CARD_ID = "showdata";
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPreferencesFile";
private TimelineManager mTimelineManager;
private LiveCard mLiveCard;


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mTimelineManager = TimelineManager.from(this);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    String voiceResults = intent.getExtras()
            .getString(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

    String MedName = voiceResults; //MedName declared

    SharedPreferences MedInfo = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = MedInfo.edit();
    editor.putString("MedName", MedName.toString());

    editor.commit();

    mLiveCard = mTimelineManager.getLiveCard(LIVE_CARD_ID);

    Intent i = new Intent(this, ShowDataActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(i);
    return START_STICKY;
    }

}
```

The intent at the bottom goes to this activity:

```
public class ShowDataActivity extends Activity {
private LiveCard mLiveCard;
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPreferencesFile";
private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

SharedPreferences MedInfo = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

Card ShowDataCard = new Card(this);
ShowDataCard.setText("IT WORKS!");
//ShowDataCard.setText(MedInfo.getString("MedName", "your medication"));
View ShowDataCardView = ShowDataCard.toView();
setContentView(ShowDataCardView);
}
```

The "ShowDataCard" that has been commented out is what I was origonally trying to do with the voice recognition but it wouldn't even work with the text "IT WORKS!"

Again: I am just trying to show a card with the text "IT WORKS"

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to get a live card to appear with just text is using widgets that are compatible with `RemoteViews`. You can find a list of them in the GDK documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/ui/live-cards

under the *Creating low-frequency live cards* section.

Here is some sample code (based on your code above) that can get that working quickly:

```
final String LIVE_CARD_ID = "showdata";

mLiveCard = mTimelineManager.getLiveCard(LIVE_CARD_ID);

RemoteViews remoteViews = 
    new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.layout_helloglass);

mLiveCard.setViews(remoteViews);

// Make sure Glass navigates to LiveCard immediately
mLiveCard.setNonSilent(true); 

mLiveCard.publish();
```

The layout file can look like this for `layout_helloglass.xml`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello, Glass!" />
</FrameLayout>
```

If you still want to navigate to another `Activity` from your `LiveCard`, you need to associate the `Activity` with a `PendingIntent` and then associate that `PendingIntent` with the `LiveCard`'s action. This would happen immediately before the `LiveCard.publish()` method:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ShowCardActivity.class); 
mLiveCard.setAction(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0));
```

That should get you up and running! Hopefully this will help.

Comment: What am I supposed to put for the LIVE_CARD_ID/what does the LIVE_CARD_ID translate or point to? Is it supposed to be the xml layout file or something else?

Comment: LIVE_CARD_ID is just a `String` constant that is used to reference the `LiveCard` you're creating so that you can `LiveCard.unpublish()` it later. It looks like that value was in your original code and probably belongs as class-level constant but I added it to the code for completeness-sake.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but it is still not publishing for me.

Comment: OK, are you trying to get voice recognition to work from the home card with the command, "it works"? Did you set up the `/res/xml/voice_trigger_start.xml` file and configure your service in `AndroidManifest.xml` to associate `MedMinderService` with the voice trigger xml file? If not, I can add in the code necessary for that to the answer.

Comment: No I did, the reason for the "it works?" is if it displays "it works", I know the card has been displayed (obviously) and that the voice recognition didn't work. If it displays what I said in the voice recognition, I know both work. ("it works" should be replaced with the voice recognition text).

Comment: I have finally gotten an activity to show something. This isn't what I want in the end but at least I sort of know what was wrong. I set the voice trigger to an activity that showed a card with simple text. I then tried the same thing but instead of simple text it was the voice recognition text. This did not work. The thing is I do not know how to setText to an arraylist<string> (if it is possible). I tried to make a workaround from `ArrayList<String> voiceResults = getIntent().getExtras()
        .getStringArrayList(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);` to the same but `String` and `.getString`

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in the GDK Sneak Peek that prevented voice prompts from creating Services. If one inserted a `Log.d()` call in a Service's `onStartCommand()` override, they would discover that it were never called.

This bug has been fixed in the GDK Preview. This behavior should not appear again.

This question was rewritten after the GDK Preview launch to remove this outdated answer. Thanks to user Falcon for notifying me.

Comment: This situation does not seem up to date. GDK Sneak Peek starts Services via voice trigger just fine now.

Comment: Fixed to reflect this. Thanks for the heads-up.